# Error: SSL connection closed unexpectedly. Error while fetching large data using postgres FDW

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-fdw

I am using postgres 13 and created a foreign server with use_remote_estimate: on and fetch_size: 10000. tableA here is a partition table by created_date. The query is running fine if the number of records is around 3M but throws an error for more than 3M records.

```
    select
      date_trunc('month', created_date)::date as month,
  count(distinct category_id) as categorys,
  count(distinct user_id) as workers
    from
      test.tableA A
    where
      is_expired = false
      and pool in (1, 2, 4, 6, 10)
      and created_date >= (select now() - interval '180 days')

    group by 1
```

Error :

```
ERROR:  SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly
CONTEXT:  remote SQL command: CLOSE c48
WARNING:  no connection to the server
Query failed
PostgreSQL said: SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly
```

Is there any configuration that needs to be added for handling large data?

Comment: On which side is that error getting reported?  What does the other side report?

Answer (score 0):

Very likely there is a network component that forcibly closes TCP connections that are idle for a certain amount of time. If you cannot fix that network component, you can try to send TCP keepalive packets more often to keep the connection busy:

- on the client side, you can set the option `keepalives_idle = 120` on the foreign server
- on the client side, you can set the parameter `tcp_keepalives_idle = 120`

That would send a keepalive packet every two minutes. Usually it is good enough to use one of the above options.

Comment: I tried using both options but it is not working in this case.

Comment: A pity. But it is a network problem, and that's where you have to search.